# What's the best option to QR code reading

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, scanning, google-mlkit

so my question is simple, I'm trying to add the QRcode reading functionality to my app.. I don't want to open another app to scan the code(I think ZXing api does that).. I was thinking in Google MLkit but I don't know if that's free of charge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Google ML Kit](https://g.co/mlkit) SDK is provided free of charge. You can find an overview of its barcode scanning feature (including support for QR code) [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning). (See full terms [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms).)